# How to invoke a servlet from bash

Tags: java, bash, servlets, jboss

I have java application server (JBoss). I deployed servlet which address is: `http://localhost:8080/Generate/Pdf`. How can I run it from bash? How can I pass parameters to run?

Comment: What do you mean by "run"? Do you want to make a HTTP request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `curl`:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/GeneratePdf
```

If you want to pass parameters, we must know more about what the servlet accepts.

Comment: in response I have a PDF, so I used: `curl http://localhost:8080/GeneratePdf?som_args > my.pdf`. PS thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 1):

use curl to execute http requests from command line

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply use `wget`:

```
wget http://localhost:8080/GeneratePdf -O path/to/output-file.pdf
```